# How to keep firebase realtime database in sync with firebase storage, the standard approch to this problem of two nested queries?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

How to keep firebase realtime database in sync with firebase storage? I am trying to store images in firebase storage.

The current scenario

1. a POJO (which contain 3 images placeholder link) is saved in the realtime database.
2. Then the 3 images are uploaded in firebase storage and on successful upload the respected placeholder links in the realtime database are updated.

Now the problem is that sometimes when the user deletes the project in between the POJO is deleted from firebase but the links are still updated.

Is there a better way of doing this ? or is there any standard approch? Thankyou for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a standard approach to this, and it can't be solved by simple configuration.  You will have to get creative and implement something that meets your specific needs.

One thing you can do is use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) triggers to mirror and delete data between the two products, so that one data in one is added, modified, or deleted, that change is reflected in the other product.  It would take at least two triggers, one database trigger, and one storage trigger, to make sure changes in either product are mirrored to the other product.  You might also need some additional process to remove or correct invalid data periodically, if that is a concern.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply, The approach I was thinking is to put a "is-deleted" boolean flag in POJO and at the end of the day or when the user quits app delete all the records with true value? does cloud functions have some advantage over this method ?

Comment: That's something you're going to have to evaluate for yourself.  Stack Overflow isn't a really good place to vet your ideas - it's for questions with clear answers.  I suggest posting to discussion forum if you want general opinion.

Comment: ok, thank you, I will try to learn more about cloud functions.

Comment: No, I don't want any opinion, it seems like a problem to me that there are two nested queries and there is a delay in between them and what happens if the state of the data from the first query changes. what is the standard way of solving this problem?

Comment: You can't eliminate the delay.  The products are not integrated in such a way that you can have transactional consistency between them.  You have to accept that they can and will reflect different data at any given moment.